# Next 13 and Mongoose - ObjectID as string

Tags: mongoose, next.js, react-server-components

So, ideally i would be able to do this:

```js
export default async function Home() {
  // const [services, categories] = await getData()
  const services = await Service.find().lean()
  const categories = await Service.distinct('category')

  return (
    <main>
      <ServicesSelector services={services} categories={categories} />
      <div className={styles.mapContainer}>
        <Map />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

without having to map through all the services to turn my _id from ObjectId into a string...

this way i always get this warning and the _id won't reach my client component
[image]

Is there a way to do this automagically?

Comment: [similar thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993#issuecomment-617375501)

Comment: or use aggregation which has a stage that converts objectid to sttring ?